# How to show legend in Pyplot Scatter 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter3d

I am making a Scatter 3D pyplot using arrays with float numbers

```
x = c_icrs.galactic.cartesian.x.value
y = c_icrs.galactic.cartesian.y.value
z = c_icrs.galactic.cartesian.z.value
```

Where x,y,z are:

```
x:array([ -65.1525587 ,   -1.76919179,    3.87621068, -193.69267564, -8.49586587])
y:array([ 99.25870537,  -1.91258061,   1.04225814, -96.36986244, 9.24999572])
z:array([ 59.09744472,  -0.40753885,  10.51755917, -64.43345929, 21.251354  ])
```

The plot:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set_title("Title")
ax.set_xlabel('X [pc]')
ax.set_ylabel('Y [pc]')
ax.set_zlabel('Z [pc]')



scatter1 = ax.scatter3D(x,y,z, s = 400, marker = '*',c=[1,2,3,4,5])
legend1 = ax.legend(['a','b','c','d','e'], title="Legend")

scatter2 = ax.scatter3D(0,0,0, s = 200, color = 'orange')
```

[image]

How do I add the other markers on the legend? only the first one is showing (a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, change your legend declaration to the following `legend1`. Then, add that legend to the `ax` with `add_artist`. Lastly, add a `label` name to your second scatter plot and call `plt.legend()` to show both. You can also add custom labels to each element legend (if you want abcde instead of 12345). If not, then just replace `*[scatter1.legend_elements()[0],['a','b','c','d','e']]` with `*scatter1.legend_elements()`.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set_title("Title")
ax.set_xlabel('X [pc]')
ax.set_ylabel('Y [pc]')
ax.set_zlabel('Z [pc]')



scatter1 = ax.scatter3D(x,y,z, s = 400, marker = '*',c=[1,2,3,4,5])
legend1 = ax.legend(*[scatter1.legend_elements()[0],['a','b','c','d','e']], 
                    title="Legend", loc='upper left')
ax.add_artist(legend1)

scatter2 = ax.scatter3D(0,0,0, s = 200, color = 'orange', label='Dot')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]